# Icinga2 - ExternalCommands filling my DB

Tags: postgresql, icinga, system-monitoring, icinga2

Today I noticed all external commands received goes to the IDO, myicinga_externalcommands table on Postgres is over 350Gb (probably around 98% of DB).

As you may have guess, my setup is a bit particular and receives A LOT of external commands, and I need to find some solution for this. This external commands are all performance data, it then goes to a RRD db and pnp4nagios, so I don't need icinga to keep anything but the very latest command for each host.

So, I have 2 questions I would like help with:

1) Can I safely delete all those external commands from the DB?

2) Can I stop icinga logging this?

If relevant, I'm now on Icinga 2.6.3-1

I hope somebody can help with this, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely delete them.

You can also configure which categories should be written. The default value attempts to set anything required for Icinga Web 2.

https://docs.icinga.com/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/toc#!/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/object-types#objecttype-idomysqlconnection

The external commands table was never used, and isn't populated when calling API actions either. So we removed it from the default in the upcoming v2.7 release.

https://github.com/Icinga/icinga2/commit/21ce07046c4438bc5e56f016d5a4c40b87e2f233

Tip for better and secure tranports: Switch to the Icinga 2 API as command transport in Icinga Web 2. The docs for v2.7 will highlight that too :)

https://github.com/Icinga/icinga2/issues/5077

Comment: I couldn't find that doc, thank you!! <3 <3

Comment: Moving to the API will be touching A LOT of very legacy scripts, but it's on my roadmap ;)